# Как правильно запускать sh-скрипты?

Tags: shell, bash, linux

1. При запуске sh-скриптов hadoop у меня все время спрашивают пароль рута (никаких манипуляций с правами я не проводил). Это напряжно, ибо приходится 3-5 раз вводить его. Можно это как-то исправить?
2. Получается, что я могу запустить sh-скрипт как `sh <scriptName>`, а могу просто `<scriptName>`. В чем разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вероятно, в самом скрипте есть несколько вызовов команд, требующих права выше, чем у текущего пользователя. Попробуйте запускать весь скрипт от имени root'а как `sudo scriptname`.
2. Разница в [командном интерпретаторе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_UNIX), который будет использован для выполнения команд скрипта. Их несколько (sh, bash, csh и др.), и реализация слегка отличается.

Comment: Если вы запустите скрипт от sudo, то домашней директорией он будет считать рутовую, а не вашу и его поведение в таком случае может отличаться.